# error handling on page design (source)

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch, eval

I have a control in GridView which converts dateformat From **MMddyyyy** To **ddMMyyyy**.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"
       Text='<%# Eval("Value1") != DBNull.Value ? 
                (Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Value1")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) : Eval("Value1") %>'>
  </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This works perfectly if it gets a **date** or **null** value.

But in my case **Value1 (the Bind Field)** can be a string containing anything. say - ***'garbageStr'***.

So it fails to convert to date and throws error.

Instead I want to display ***null*** or ***blank value*** when it fails to convert to DateTime format.

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

you can define a method for this purpose in code behind , and call it, then in method implementation try conversion in  `DateTime.TryParse` and return string accrdingly

Comment: Why dont you use DateTime.TryParse

Comment: I must have to pass out DateTime; which must be declared before.
I cannot define it in passing the parameter.
Thats the problem. 
??!?

Comment: you dont need to, it all should be inside the in the method in codebehind

Answer (score 2):

In your aspx file:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# ReturnPropertDateTime(Eval("Value1")) %>'>   </asp:Label>
```

In your Code Behind file:

```
protected DateTime ReturnPropertDateTime(object val)
{
        DateTime dt = null;
         string dateTimeValue = Convert.ToString(val);
    DateTime dateTime2;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeValue.ToString("ddMMyyyy"), out dateTime2))
    {
        dt = dateTime2;     
      }
    else
    {
         dt = // Just Assign Default date time value you want.
    }

return dt;

}
```

Although its tedious, but you can make your aspx file more readable through this approach as it prevents clutering and provide flexible handling.

Comment: I that I can do in code behind anyway while binding.
But I wanted it to handle it in .aspx(design) page.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want the handling to be done in code-behind? Your aspx looks quite messy.

Comment: Nope. But I tried out that way. And there are too many fields like this - around 30 fields total.
I have to change the whole code. & also these fields are in GridView, so I have to handle with some extra efforts.

Comment: I can use Try...Catch also. If it is possible on design page. !?

Comment: Well, you can either put some less efforts or write a robust code with better handling. Your choice.